# Can I make a career at my current job?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, job-change, work-experience, software-engineering

I am currently working as a frontend software developer, but after 2 years working at the company I work for I feel like they are just keeping me at stock, backup or assistance.
I didn't say much, but they keep hiring amateurs that don't know how unit testing or good software architecture works. While those people have a chance to grow, I don't really get a chance to flourish and release my full potential.
My knowledge regarding software development (fullstack, architecture, requirements engineering, ui/ux, automated testing etc.) is really big and I asked them to give me a chance to actually lead a project from start to finish or promote me, however nothing is happening.
I'm actually very motivated and dedicated but I feel like I'm being punished for it.

However recently something happened: There was a certain position I was aiming for in the company since I'm the only one who has the necessary skills (apart from 1 more guy) and they said they would give me a chance. They know that my current position doesn't fulfill me and that I'm not making any progress in my career. They would also benefit from my skills.
They said ok, they would give me a probation for the promotion and that I will have a chance to prove my skills on our next big project.
However they gave the position, which they never gave to someone before, to another guy (they know he used to mob me when I was a new employee) and included me in the project as a simple assistant developer.
Recently there is a vacant position as frontend lead developer. I asked them if we could have a discussion about me filling the position as I would be interested. No reply. I feel like I'm being totally ignored and that they are keeping me in "stock".

I also noticed that I'm being excluded a lot by colleagues, even though they know I have a lot of knowledge they can benefit from. They also never include me as a reviewer in any pull requests that isn't part of the project I'm working on, even though they know I can give a lot of constructive feedback and input.

What should I do? Something feels off.

Comment: Sorry, aren't you [already a lead developer at your company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183229/working-with-very-bad-code-but-on-a-deadline)?

Comment: If I may ask - what is your overall work experience?

Comment: @SouravGhosh In total 5 years. Automated unit testing and e2e testing, backend and frontend development. React, vue, angular. Cross plattform development. Windows 10 apps. Requirement Engineering. Software architecture. User Interface Design and UX. The issue is, at my current job im hired as a frontend developer but the tasks are too underwhelming.

Comment: Please forgive me for mentioning it, but if your User ID has anything to do with reality then it could impact the overall situation you describe.

Comment: Have you tried to look for new jobs with bigger responsibilities in new companies ?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you're not as good as you think you are and/or your colleagues aren't as terrible as you think?

Answer (score 16):

> Something feels off.

Yes. You tried multiple times to advance and you were denied every single time.

It would helpful to find out WHY you were denied. If you have a somewhat reasonable boss, you can sit down with them and have an open conversation about your strength and weaknesses and their assessment why you didn't get the other jobs/roles. Leadership roles do require a lot more than technical skills: communication, organizational awareness, ability to motivate and excite people, cultural sensitivities, staying organized, clear goals and objectives, etc. It's possible that you have one or more blind spots that you are not aware of.

It's also possible that your management think a lot less of your skills than you do. It's also possible that just don't like you or don't think that you have what it takes.

> What should I do?

That depends on your analysis. If there are behaviors or skill gaps that hold you back, start working on them. If the just don't like or want you around, it's time to move on.

Comment: ...and if they do you the favor and give you an honest evaluation of your weaknesses: **Don't argue**. Don't try to explain yourself and show them that they are wrong. Getting honest feedback is incredibly hard, and people won't do it if you make them feel uncomfortable. Shut up, listen, maybe ask clarifying questions if anything is unclear, listen again, **thank them for being so honest**, go home and reflect on everything they said. Remember that they are doing you a big favor.

Answer (score 10):

> I asked them if we could have a discussion about me filling the position as I would be interested. No reply. I feel like im being totally ignored and that they are keeping me in "stock".

I know it's something of a cliche as an answer: but if you have no advancement at your current company then it's time to look for a new one. This is an in-demand sector, so if your skills are as good as you think they are, you shouldn't struggle to find another employer who'll pay you more.

And if you can't find someone who will, then maybe you weren't ready for that promotion.

Comment: You are right. As simple as this asnwer may sound, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Even if you know what you are missing, going a few years without personal management and growth is a sign you have better change job. Better prove your worth somewhere else after a pay raise than prove your worth and hope for a raise/promotion.

Comment: @JayZ I know that past employees actually had the same issue as me. There is no progression. I didnt ask for a pay raise because I wanted them to first give me a chance to release my full potential. I actually told them.

Answer (score 7):

Reading the way you described your colleague's code in [this previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183229/working-with-very-bad-code-but-on-a-deadline) is it possible that your company thinks that you are not a team player?

Perhaps you need to change your approach, yes there are best practices but you also need to appreciate that very few people come to work to deliberately do a bad job - Most are just trying to get the job done and often with pressure on them.

You could try asking your manager for some constructive feedback in your one to one or appraisal.

Comment: In my anual performance review teamwork and behavior was rated as very good. Never had any critics in that regard. I did ask for additional feedback but im being told its a question of resource management etc. I still feel like im being excluded in many key decisions however and dont get a chance to make the next step. I also know that some past employees had similar issues as what im facing now.

Comment: Maybe some introspection is needed then, you've described your colleague's code as garbage. How would you feel if someone put you on a task where you were not an expert and your work was described as garbage?

Answer (score 1):

You've tried; I've actually been in the same position as yourself. If management feel you're strongest in your current role, as opposed to a different one, they'll ignore you and hope that the "problem goes away on it's own". By the sounds of it, they're more than happy with the work you're outputting, but for whatever reason don't want to give you a step up (in my experience, this is usually political).

Now, unintentionally they may get what they want - 2 years is a good time to consider moving on anyway. Especially for a developer. I would put the feelers out and maybe interview for the position you'd like to attain. Nothing to lose here really; it will allow you to be assessed externally, and will allow you to pinpoint whether this is a political issue at your company or whether you actually are ready for such a position.